# Hidden objects on one frame need to stay hidden when returning to the frame

Tags: actionscript-3

I have created point and click games in AS2 but now developing in AS3. When you click an object to add to your inventory the object is .visible=false; Then when you leave a room (frame) and return the object would still remain .visible=false;
I achieved this in AS2 using the following:

(set up of a movieclip instance MCTake)

```
var MCTakeVisible;
MCTake._visible=MCTakeVisible;
```

(when I click the movieclip)

```
MCTake._visible=false;
MCTakeVisible=false;
MCTake._visible=MCTakeVisible;
```

Now the object is gone no matter how many times I return back to the frame. My question is what is the AS3 equivalent to this behavior.
Also vise-versa. If an object is hidden at first and made to appear like an open door that stays open. I used the following for that in AS2:

```
if(MCTakeVisible == undefined) MCTakeVisible = false;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Basicly the same works in AS3, but the property is `.visible`. Also, define variables, f.ex. `var MCTakeVisible:Boolean;` and they will be `false` as default.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly with such a minor change.